How do I create a custom hook like useState for context value to get previous state value?
I have a context like this
ProductProvider.js
import React, { createContext, useMemo } from 'react'

const INITIAL_HANDLER = {
  sortType: null,
  offset: 0
}

export const ProductProviderContext = createContext({
  ...INITIAL_HANDLER,
  setHandler: () => null
})

export default ({ children }) => {
  const [data, setData] = React.useState(INITIAL_HANDLER)

  const setHandler = (value) => {
    setData({ ...data, ...value })
  }

  const contextValue = useMemo(() => ({
    ...data,
    setHandler
  }), [data])

  return (
    <ProductProviderContext.Provider value={contextValue}>
      {children}
    </ProductProviderContext.Provider>
  )
}

And in one of my child component that has been wrapped inside ProductProvider I want to call setHandler but I want to access the last value of data like the useState callback function so when I access a ProductProviderContext from child, I can use setHandler like useState (either passing changed value directly or using callback to get previous data value).
Example usage that I expect setHandler to accept:
setHandler({ sortType: 'popular' })
// or I can use it like this
setHandler(prevData => ({ offset: prevData.offset++ }))

How do I refactor the setHandler so I can call setHandler like above?

Hmmm, you can try in ProductProvider.js
...

const setHandler = (value) => {
   setData((prevData) => (typeof value === 'function' ? value(prevData) : { ...prevData, ...value }));   };

...


The setData state updater function already does exactly what you are asking to do, so you can just pass it down directly to consumers if you like.
export default ({ children }) => {
  const [data, setData] = React.useState(INITIAL_HANDLER);

  const contextValue = useMemo(() => ({
    ...data,
    setHandler: setData // <-- pass setData callback down
  }), [data]);

  return (
    <ProductProviderContext.Provider value={contextValue}>
      {children}
    </ProductProviderContext.Provider>
  );
}

Or you can update setHandler to consume a value that is either a value or a callback function that is passed to the setData state updater function.
export default ({ children }) => {
  const [data, setData] = React.useState(INITIAL_HANDLER);

  const setHandler = (valueOrCallback) => {
    setData(valueOrCallback);
  };

  const contextValue = useMemo(() => ({
    ...data,
    setHandler
  }), [data]);

  return (
    <ProductProviderContext.Provider value={contextValue}>
      {children}
    </ProductProviderContext.Provider>
  )
}

Either implementation should allow you to pass a value directly.
setHandler({ sortType: 'popular' });

Or pass an updater callback. Be sure to not mutate the current state though (e.g. you still need to apply a mutable state update!).
setHandler(prevData => ({ 
  ...prevData,                // <-- shallow copy current state
  offset: prevData.offset + 1 // <-- don't mutate prevData.offset
}));

If the issue is that you would like to pass a value to setHandler and have it shallow merged into the existing state instead of replacing it entirely, while still allowing for functional state updates, then consider the following:
export default ({ children }) => {
  const [data, setData] = React.useState(INITIAL_HANDLER);

  const setHandler = (valueOrCallback) => {
    setData(data => {
      if (typeof valueOrCallback === "function") {
        // function callback, invoke function and pass current state
        return valueOrCallback(data);
      } else {
        // object, shallow copy current state and new state
        // value into new state reference
        return {
          ...data,
          ...valueOrCallback,
        };
      }
    });
  };

  const contextValue = useMemo(() => ({
    ...data,
    setHandler
  }), [data]);

  return (
    <ProductProviderContext.Provider value={contextValue}>
      {children}
    </ProductProviderContext.Provider>
  )
}


with current suggestion, does it make the data replace the value? i mean, if my data contain value {foo:1, bar:2} and I call setHandler({foo:2}), doesn't that's make the value of data become {foo:2} instead of {foo:2, bar:2}?

@flix Yes, that's how the useState hook and React state works. If you pass a value, the state is set to that value. This is why the updater function syntax is available, so you have more control over the next computed state value, e.g. you need to merge updates into the existing state value. See my additional comment about applying correct mutable state updates.

unfortunately, I've used setHandler({onlyChangedObject}) in many place, it's a bit pain to change all setHandler to become a callback. :(

@flix What is there to change if it already accepts a value or a callback? What is the real problem you are trying to solve? Are you basically asking how to create a callback that shallow merges a value into the current state for you so you don't need to use the functional state update pattern? That along with the regular normal functional state update syntax?
